# Scrollbar in HTML page not working well when a header is added

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar

I have a page layout with multiple sections (divs). There is a banner and then there are two main vertical sections. The left section has a scrollbar so the user can scroll down to see all the links. This works fine as long as I don't have the banner/header part. When I add the header, the scrollbar does not go down all the way (or does not start right from the last item, but only after a couple of the items are already covered). Can someone please help me with this peculiar problem?

without the header, scrollbar works fine
[image: without the header, scrollbar works fine]

[image: with the header, scollbar does not show all items in the left-section]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Two Columns with Independent Scrollbars</title>
    <style>

        /* Styles for the container */
        .container {
            display: flex; /* Use Flexbox */
            height: 100vh; /* Take up all vertical space */
        }

        /* Styles for the left section */
        .left-section {
            width: 30%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Set the background color for the left section */
            overflow-y: auto; /* Add vertical scroll if needed */
        }

        /* Styles for the right section */
        .right-section {
            width: 70%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #e0e0e0; /* Set the background color for the right section */
            
        }

        /* Style for links */
        .left-section a {
            display: block; /* Each link on a new line */
            margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add spacing between links */
            text-decoration: none;
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Banner Section -->
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>
        <p>This is the banner section of the page.</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- if i remove the div above, the "left-section" works fine. -->
    
    <!-- Container for both sections -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Left Section with Independent Scrollbar -->
        <div class="left-section">
            <h3>Drawings</h3>
            <!-- Drawing Searches -->
            <a href="#" id="singleDrawing">Single CAD Entry</a>
            <a href="#" id="allRevsCAD">Single CAD Entry - All Revision</a>
            <a href="#" id="multipleDrawings">Multiple CAD Entries</a>
            <a href="#" id="trackingNumber">Tracking Number Entry</a>
            <hr>
            <a href="#" id="part">Single Part Drawings</a>
            <a href="#" id="assembly">All Drawings for a Part Assembly</a>
             <!-- Content for the right section goes here -->
            <h3>Procurement</h3>
            <a href="#" id="techPack">Tech. Package Download</a>
            
            <h3>Reports</h3>
            <a href="#" id="BOMReport">Multi-level BOM</a>
            <a href="#" id="CADStructure">CAD Structure</a>
            <a href="#" id="partHistory">Part Change History Report</a>
            <a href="#" id="MIDB">MIDB</a>
            <hr>
            <a href="#" id="shaftDetail">Shaft Detail</a>
            <a href="#" id="shaftVariations">Shaft Variations</a>
            <a href="#" id="rotorDetail">Rotor Assembly Detail</a>
            <a href="#" id="rotorVariations">Rotor Assembly Variations</a>
            <a href="#" id="shaftDetail">Shaft Detail</a>
            <a href="#" id="shaftVariations">Shaft Variations</a>
            <a href="#" id="rotorDetail">Rotor Assembly Detail</a>
            <a href="#" id="rotorVariations">Rotor Assembly Variations</a>
            <h3>Drawings</h3>
            <!-- Drawing Searches -->
            <a href="#" id="singleDrawing">Single CAD Entry</a>
            <a href="#" id="allRevsCAD">Single CAD Entry - All Revision</a>
            <a href="#" id="multipleDrawings">Multiple CAD Entries</a>
            <a href="#" id="trackingNumber">Tracking Number Entry</a>
            <hr>
            <a href="#" id="part">Single Part Drawings</a>
            <a href="#" id="assembly">All Drawings for a Part Assembly</a>
             <!-- Content for the right section goes here -->
            <h3>Procurement</h3>
            <a href="#" id="techPack">Tech. Package Download</a>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Right Section with Independent Scrollbar -->
        <div class="right-section">
           
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried a lot of different things, change the div layout, change to gridlayout, I get the same result in every case. When I don't have the header, the scrollbar works fine, but as soon as I add the header, it falls short of the entire left section.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
.banner {
    height: 20vh;
}

.container {
    display: flex; 
    height: 80vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does, I see last element when I scroll to the end of left part even you have banner section. To see it, you just need to scroll while your mouse is on left area.

Comment: If you have still problem, you should set "height" to left area. For example
.left-section {
    height: 90vh;
}

or 

.left-section {
    height: calc(100vh - bannerSectionHeight);
}

it will calculate and automatically set height